# Eclipse not finding file?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I am using eclipse and I have my text file in the correct directory (src folder). I just want to read the file and count all the words in it. For some reason I am getting a file not found exception being thrown.

here is my code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

public static int getSizeOfDictionary(File dictionary)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    int count = 0;

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(dictionary);
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        reader.nextLine();
        count++;
    }
    reader.close();
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File test = new File("words.txt");

    System.out.println(getSizeOfDictionary(test));

   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this.getClass().getResource("words.txt") which will find that file on the current classpath.

From the main method you could use: Tester.class.getResource("words.txt")

Comment: When I try that, I get an error saying that my tester class does not have getResourceAsFile method.

Comment: Sorry, spelled it our for you. Please try now.

Comment: a side note: OP: you may omit `this` just to have `getClass().getResourceAsFile(...)` `:)`

Comment: Thanks, but I still get an error stating "Cannot use this in a static context" Im assuming I cant use this due to it being in my main method.

Comment: One more try. How about now?

Comment: @user56029283888 Don't use getClass(). Use the other one for the main method I specified.

Comment: It works now, but I had to change getResourceAsFile to getResource

Answer (score 3):

when eclipse launches jvm it sets current directory to project base directory generally (unless you modify the default current directory)

```
${workspace_loc}/project_name
```

so you need to change your `File` initialization to

```
File test = new File("src/words.txt");
```

---

**Note:**

It will just be limited to this project structure, if you export it to jar it will not work any more, I assume you just need it as part of exercise

Comment: Thank you very much. Interesting because I do not remember adding the src/ last time I used eclipse.

Comment: and what if you run your code from outside the eclipse ??

Comment: then you would have to run it from correct location with right classpath, OP's thing is very tightly connected with eclipse project structure

Comment: yeah exactly, thats why this is not the permanent solution, you need to access the source file using Classname.getClass() methos

Answer (score 0):

You have to use property class to access your file within class-path and source folder

you can try like:

> this.getClass().getResourceAsFile("words.txt")

Comment: -1 because you don't **HAVE** to use reflection or a property class. you _may_ use relative paths as @JigarJoshi has done. this could be misleading

Comment: and it is the process of reflection basically to getting the class-path of the source.
when it gives exception, you can easily checkout the stack trace.. this is the concept of reflection....